# sentinel dashboard 1.8.0 add rule success,but the list page show the rule data nothing

Tags: sentinel, nacos

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZeLKD.png)

left menu i can see my path, when i add a rule, the Api response success and forward to the rule list page, bug nothing in the page.

sentinel dashboard v1.8.0 running in localhost:8080

sms-service can be running also

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qzAB7.png)

my project pom such as :

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.alibaba.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-alibaba-nacos-discovery</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.alibaba.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-alibaba-nacos-config</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.alibaba.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-alibaba-sentinel</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.alibaba</groupId>
        <artifactId>fastjson</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.8</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-redis</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>io.lettuce</groupId>
                <artifactId>lettuce-core</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>redis.clients</groupId>
        <artifactId>jedis</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>8.0.20</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.alibaba</groupId>
        <artifactId>druid-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.8</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

You must ensure that the client service is accessible to the sentinel dashboard, because the sentinel dashboard does not store rule data, it only sends the rule to the client, the client restarts the rule and the rule becomes invalid.

You can visit [here](https://github.com/alibaba/Sentinel/wiki/%E5%8A%A8%E6%80%81%E8%A7%84%E5%88%99%E6%89%A9%E5%B1%95) to write rules to persistence